# How to constrain CodedUI to begin search from parent object?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm attempting to use CodedUI in a code-first approach (page object pattern) for a WPF UI.  I'm able to navigate to a specific list item within a groupbox within a tab on the main window.  Each list item contains a checkbox along with some other content; I'd like to automate clicking the checkbox, but I'm getting an exception with the message 'Search may have failed at " TabList as it may have virtualized children...'

The only thing is that I'm setting the containing `WpfListItem` as the parent for the `WpfCheckBox` per the following code:

```
public class ConfigItem 
{
    private readonly WpfListItem _instance;

    public WecoConfigItem([NotNull] WpfListItem instance)
    {
        if (instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public ConfigItem SelectConfiguration()
    {
        var checkBox = new WpfCheckBox(_instance);
        _instance.DrawHighlight();
        checkBox.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCheckBox.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "cbIsSelected");
        Mouse.Click(checkBox);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The failure occurs in the SelectConfiguration method.  During test execution, the corresponding `ListItem` is highlighted, but then in the html output the recorded image highlights the application.  So, some questions:

1. Why is the search starting from the application window when I'm providing the `WpfListItem` as the parent in the constructor?
2. Am I doing something that is causing the discrepancy between the `DrawHighlight()` output and the HTML output?
3. How do I constrain the search to begin with the `WpfListItem` parent object, for a code-first page object pattern approach?

**EDIT:** The search is actually beginning from the top-level application, not the tab - I was looking at a stale HTML log.  Problem statement is still essentially the same.

Comment: Where and how are u initializing  _instance ? You probably will have to start from the application and give the entire hierarchy throughout. It's probably because of how MSAA/UIA frameworks are architectured. Check this out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2011/04/21/illustration-of-coded-ui-test-playback-failure-search-may-have-failed-at-controlx-as-it-may-have-virtualized-children/

Answer (score 0):

The moment you call DrawHighlight() you are initiating a search. The next statement then gives additional search criteria and then you access the control again (Mouse.click()), but then you are reading from cache. I assume that you either need to disable the cache by setting the SearchOptions to AlwaysSearch or add the criteria before you call DrawHighlight().